# how to work reusable state in class components?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, react-scripts

do class components support Reusable State in React 18? [I wrote an example](https://codesandbox.io/s/class-reusable-state-e9we9u)

```js
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("componentDidMount");
    if (!this.mounted) {
      this.fetchData();
      this.mounted = true;
    }
  }

  fetchData() {
    fetch().then((data) => {
      this.setState((statePrev) => {
        console.log("prev data", statePrev); // always null after editing the file of this component and triggering Fast Refresh, how to work reusable state in class components?
        return {
          data: [
            ...(Array.isArray(statePrev?.data) ? statePrev?.data : []),
            ...data
          ]
        };
      });
    });
  }
```

I expected that when I edit and save the component file and React Refresh is triggered then statePrev will contain the previous state but it is always null

second problem is when React Refresh is triggered, the this.mounted property also does not work to determine that the mounting has occurred and you do not need to run fetch again